# Correctly writing a Zone File for a nameserver

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone

I need to write a zone file for a new company domain. Let's say the company owns company.com and I need to write a zone file for 2 domains play1.playground.company.com and play2.playground.company.com . When defining the zone file Origin line, do I need to put in the whole FQDN play1.playground.company.com. or just play1.playground is enough? Will the following zone file work out?

```
$ORIGIN play1.playground.company.com.
$TTL 3600
@        IN    SOA      ns hostmaster ( 1614244859 7200 3600 1209600 3600 )
@        IN     NS    ns
@        IN     A    1.1.1.1
@        IN    MX    10 mail
ns       IN    A    10.0.0.2
mail     IN    A    10.0.0.1
www      IN    CNAME    play1.playground.company.com.
wwwtest  IN     CNAME    www
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$ORIGIN` defines how unqualified names in your zone file should be completed.

You can use anything and even redefine  `$ORIGIN` to change that substitution behavior for subsequent records in the same zone file.

But that will probably lead to a complete mess.

`$ORIGIN` should be fully qualified and end in . dot.

By convention `$ORIGIN` should be set to zone name that zone file belongs to and that is what Bind will do when it is not explicitly defined.

See also https://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/origin.html

**Afterthought**: I have also seen zonefiles where `$ORIGIN` is set to only the dot `.`.

That has the result that effectively no substitution takes place. That forces an zone administrator to always use FQDN's everywhere and means you can't use the `@` shorthand but also prevents situations such as the example below where a missing full stop after what was intended as an FQDN results in a CNAME record pointing to `play1.playground.company.com.play1.playground.company.com.`

```
$ORIGIN play1.playground.company.com.
www      IN    CNAME    play1.playground.company.com
```

I don't know if doing that makes a lot more sense but it does make both the record with and without the terminating `.` behave identical and as a sloppy zone administrator expects :

```
$ORIGIN .
www.play1.playground.company.com   IN  CNAME  play1.playground.company.com 
www.play1.playground.company.com.  IN  CNAME  play1.playground.company.com.
```